# GameCenter Orientation Problems

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, game-center

I got a lot of problems implementing Game Center.

My game its based on Cocos2d But my Menu I do it with XIB. So the main window i make it like this:

- UIWindow
- UINavigationController

  - Navigation Bar
  - UIViewController [Menu]
  - UINavigationItem

When i click on Play I create a new View Controller called Menu2Game.h.m.xib And i add the OpenGL to this view, and then Menu2Game add it to my menu View

```
    menu2Game = [[Menu2Game alloc] initWithNibName:@"Menu2Game" bundle:nil];
    [menu2Game setView:glView];
    [self.view addSubview: menu2Game.view];
```

I don't know why I can't add it directly... But when I click on leaderboards I do the same thing. Presenting the view directly on Menu doesn't work.

```
    UIViewController *tempView = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:tempView.view];
    [[GameCenter sharedGameCenter] showLeaderboard:tempView];
```

And when I call my leaderbords its this code.

```
if ([self isGameCenterAvailable]) {
    GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

    if (leaderboardController != nil) {
        screen = screen2;
        leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;       
        [screen presentModalViewController: leaderboardController animated: YES];
        [leaderboardController setCategory:@"015.1"];leaderboardController.view.frame.origin.y);
        leaderboardController.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
        leaderboardController.view.center = CGPointMake(240, 160);
    }

}
```

The problem here its that doesn't respects the application Orientation

If its in Landscape. It start in 80, 320, And finish in 480, 320
It appears and you can use it but appears not in ----> this direction it moves like with 45 degrees

And if you hold the phone in Portrait [Any]. It appears only a small fragment of the leader boards, Facing the real orientation, but the coordinated are different it takes the ones you are holding. And in my plist its not permuted portrait.

How could i fix this? I got 1 week to finish this game and this is the only thing I miss.

Thanks to everybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but just create should rotate and return true.., and eliminate all the code that modify the game center

this one:

```
    [leaderboardController setCategory:@"015.1"];leaderboardController.view.frame.origin.y);
    leaderboardController.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
    leaderboardController.view.center = CGPointMake(240, 160);
}
```